# Is multiple inheritance needed?

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, object-composition

I have a situation like below:

```cpp
class A {
    virtual void f() { /*some default impl here*/}
    virtual void g() { /*some default impl here*/}
};

class B : public A {
    virtual void f() { /* do some specific stuff and call parent's f()*/}
    virtual void g() { /* do some specific stuff and call parent's g()*/}
};

class C : public A {
    virtual void f() { /* do some specific stuff and call parent's f()*/}
    virtual void g() { /* do some specific stuff and call parent's g()*/}
};

class mixed /* I don't know how to derive*/ {
    virtual void f() { /* call B::f()*/}
    virtual void g() { /* call C::g()*/}
};
```

I'm thinking about multiple inheritance here. I.e., make `mixed` derived from `B` and `C`.
But there are some known problems (for example,
[Diamond problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem)).

Another solution could be composition.

But what is the correct solution, please advise :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If `A` is just an interface (i.e. it doesn't have meaningful data members), you could just make `mixed` inerherit from `A`, and then have two data members: `B b;` and `C c;`. Then, in its `f()` you call `b.f()` and in `g()` you call `c.g()`. Or perhaps you could split `A` up into two different classes, one with `f()` and one with `g()`, and then two different `B`s and `C`s, each inheriting from the proper parent, from which `mixed` could then inherit.

Answer (score 4):

> some known problems (for example, Diamond problem).

First: There is no diamond pattern unless you explicitly create one.

```
 class mixed: public B, public C
```

This will make mixed inherit from B and C. With each having their own explicit A (no diamond).

Since both B and C have virtual members derived from A it becomes ambiguous which one should be called but you have solved that by having explicit definitions of all virtuals in `mixed` (so problem solved).

```
  void mixed::f() { B::f();} // works fine.
```

Now even if you explicitly create a diamond.

Note: The diamond pattern does not appear normally. The diamond pattern is a design decision you must **explicitly** make and you use it to solve certain types of problem (by using virtual inheritance).

```
class B: public virtual A ...
class C: public virtual A ...
class mixed: public B, public C ...
```

You still don't have a problem. Because `mixed::f()` only uses the `B` branch (and then A). While `mixed::g()` only uses the `C` branch (and then A).

Even if `A` has its own state (though that is probably a bad idea, usually best to use interfaces as a virtual base class) then we don't have a problem because `mixed::f()` and `mixed::g()` only call a function in one child (the problems start to occur if they call both sides and the state of `A` is getting mutated by both calls.

> Another solution could be composition.

That would also work.

```
 class mixed: public A
 {
     B    b;
     C    c;
     public:
         virtual void f() override {b.f();}
         virtual void g() override {c.g();}
     ....
 };
```

> But what is the correct solution

There is no correct solution. That will depend a lot on the details that you have not mentioned (like what are the details of A).

**BUT** the general advice is to prefer composition over inheritance, but that is only general advice specifics will always boil down to the actual problem being solved.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that each method has to "do stuff" before calling the parent causes the problem.

One solution would be to have `A` and `B` as members in the `mixed` class. Then you can control what you need to do with them in `mixed::f()` and `mixed::g()`

If you need to, you could create a base class `base` with *pure virtual* functions `f()`, and `g()`. `mixed` can inherit from that, and so could `A`, `B` and `C`. You allude to this possibility when you moot *composition*.

Answer (score 3):

I think you might be looking for something like this.  (Sorry, it's a large pile of code but it's really straight-forward.)

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
  virtual void
  f()
  {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
  }

  virtual void
  g()
  {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
  }

  // Don't forget the virtual destructor.
  virtual ~A() noexcept = default;
};

struct B : virtual A
{
  virtual void
  f() override
  {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
    A::f();
  }

  virtual void
  g() override
  {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
    A::g();
  }
};

struct C : virtual A
{
  virtual void
  f() override
  {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
    A::f();
  }

  virtual void
  g() override
  {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
    A::g();
  }
};

struct D : virtual B, virtual C
{
  virtual void
  f() override
  {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
    B::f();
  }

  virtual void
  g() override
  {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
    C::g();
  }
};

int
main()
{
  D d {};
  d.f();
  std::cout << '\n';
  d.g();
}
```

[`override`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) is a C++11 feature to have the compiler check you're actually overriding.  Using it is good practice but not required if your compiler doesn't support it.  [`__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html) is a GCC extension to get a string literal that names the current function's signature.  Standard C++ has `__func__` but it's less useful here.  You could type the strings yourself if your compiler has no feature comparable to `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`.

Output:

```
virtual void D::f()
virtual void B::f()
virtual void A::f()

virtual void D::g()
virtual void C::g()
virtual void A::g()
```

It works, but I don't consider this pretty code.  Composition would probably be the better solution here.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative to virtual inheritance: using [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to mix in the functionality of `B` and `C` into `M`, while sharing a common `A`, *without* the overhead of vtables.

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    int a;
};

template <typename T>
struct B
{
    A *get_base_a() {return static_cast<T*>(this);}
    void print_a() {std::cout << get_base_a()->a << '\n';}
};

template <typename T>
struct C
{
    A *get_base_a() {return static_cast<T*>(this);}
    void print_a() {std::cout << get_base_a()->a << '\n';}
};

struct M : A, B<M>, C<M>
{
};

int main()
{
    M m;
    m.a = 1;
    m.B::print_a();
    m.C::print_a();
    return 0;
}
```

Note however, that you will not be able to pass an `M*` to a function that expects a `B*` or a `C*`.